# Center of gravity of Athletes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, everyday-life

[image]

Can someone please give me a clear explanation for the (b) Part of this question. Not the (a) Part of it. Also, Explain the importance of center of mass in deciding which type of jump is better.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please see [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) for our homework policy :)

Answer (score 1):

Taking the center of mass higher above the ground requires more energy.

In the Fosbury flop, the athlete can pass over the bar even when their center of mass is well below the bar. So this takes lesser energy and effort than the other straddle jump.Hence it is more preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, while performing a Fosbury Flop, the athlete's arms and legs form an arc around the rod. As the lower end of the arc is at a lesser height, it's centre of mass is low and hence, significantly less effort (work) is required in performing it. In the straddle jump, the athlete's center of mass is relatively higher, so , the effort needed is more.